# Find all positive integers a,b,c to the equation a!b!= a!+b!+c!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I think I have proved that that **a** cannot be greater than **b** (ie **a** & **b** must be equal) then using this fact I got a quadratic in terms of a and c, trying out some values I got that (3,3,4) is a solution, but how do I prove this is the only solution or if this is not the only solution then what are the other solutions and how do I find them?

Comment: For completeness, I assume that your proof for $a=b$ is like this: If $a<b$, then the left hand side is divisible by $a!$, hence so is $c!$, i.e., $c\ge a$. The left hand side is evenly divisible by $(a+1)!$, but on the right we get either $\frac1{a+1}$ or $\frac 2{a+1}$ plus an integer, hence $a+1\mid 2$

Comment: If b is is less than a, you have two cases to analyse **c>b>a** or **b>c>a** you can express both **a** & **c** in terms of **b** then then you have a quadratic in terms of **b**,in the end you find the solution to this quadratic is not an integer (for both cases) and you are done.

Comment: Why does $a=b$?

Comment: @CulverKwan Once you know $c \ge b$ (as in HVE's comment above) or the even better bound $c \ge b+1$ (which is how I start [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4747025/72968)) then you can use divisibility to show $a=b$. Roughly, my argument was that without loss of generality $b\ge a$ so $b!$ is a multiple of $a!$. As $c\ge b$ then $c!$ is a multiple of $b!$ and $a!=a!b!-b!-c!$ is a multiple of $b!$ also. So $a!=b!$. A slightly different proof by contradiction can be seen in [Mike's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3338412/72968), which is essentially the same as HVE's comment

Answer (score 3):

If you prove that a=b, c>a

$a!(a!-2)=c!$ => $a+1|a!-2$

if $a+1$ is prime, $a+1|a!+1$ =>$a+1|3$ => $a= 2$, but it is not an example

if $a+1 = a_1a_2, 1< a_1 < a_2 < a $, $a+1| a!$ => $a+1|2$ => a=1, but it is not an example

So, $a+1 = p^2$, p is prime;

if p>2, $a! = C*p*(2p)$, so $a+1| a!$  => as in previous case

So, $a+1 = 2^2$

Comment: $a!-2=k_1(a+1), a!+1 =k_2(a+1)$ => $3=(k_2-k_1)(a+1)$

Comment: Yeah,I just noted that you *used* $a+1\mid a!+1$, not concluded it

Comment: Why must $(a+1)$ divide $a!-2$? This is true if $(a+1)$ is prime, but what if $(a+1)$ is composite? I am not following.

Comment: @Mike Since $c>a$ we must have $a! | c!$ and in particular $a! - 2 = c!/a! = (a+1)(a+2)\cdots c$

Comment: I see it now, thanks @Silverfish

Comment: Using [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) to claim if $a+1$ is prime, it divides $a!+1$ (and as it also divides $a!-2$, then $a+1\mid 3$) is very neat, but for a high school contest feels excessive. Trying to keep the spirit of this answer: since $a\ge 3$, the LHS $a!-2$ is even. If $a+1$ is prime it's an odd prime so RHS $c!/a!$ can't just be $a+1$. We need $c\ge a+2$ so RHS also has factor $(a+2)$. But this is even, so $a/2+1$ is also a factor of RHS and hence of LHS $a!-2$. Also $a/2+1<a+1$ so $(a/2+1)|a!$. Hence $(a/2+1)|2$ and $a=2$, which isn't a solution

Answer (score 2):

I have a different approach to this. [ETA: I put $x=a, y=b,z=c$ and we assume that $x,y,z$ are POSITIVE integers]

First, assume that the inequalities $\max\{x,y,z\} \ge 4$ and $x \le y \le z$ hold. [It is clear that we may assume WLOG that we may assume the inequality $x \le y$ holds, we explain at the bottom why we may also assume the inequality $y \le z$.]

Next, for each integer $N$ let $\ell(N)$ be the largest power of 3 dividing $N$.

> Claim 1: The equation $x=y$ must hold.

Indeed, suppose otherwise. Then the string of inequalities $x<y \le z$ hold and furthermore $x,y,z$ satisfy

$$y! = 1 + y!/x! +z!/x!$$

note that if $y>x$ then all but the $1$ are divisible by $x+1$ [because the string of inequalities $x < y \le z$ hold], which is impossible.

> Claim 2: Either $z < y+3$ or $x=y \le 3$.

Indeed suppose $z \ge x+3$. Then $z! = Bx!$ for some multiple $B$ of 3. Furthermore, $x!+y!+z! = 2x!+Bx!$ [by Claim 1] So $\ell(x!+y!+z!) = \ell(x!)$. However, $\ell(x!y!)= \ell(x!)+\ell(y!)=2\ell(x!)$. Thus by this and Claim 1 $x$ and $y$ must satisfy $x=y<3$ and Claim 2 follows.

> Claim 3: If $z$ satisfies $z \le x+2$ then $x \le 5$ and $z\le 7$.

Indeed, by Claim 1 $x=y$, so $x$ and $z$ must satisfy

$$(2 + z!/x!)x! = x! \times x!$$

Plugging in $z \le x+2$ and dividing both sides by $x!$ into the above gives

$$2+(x+1)(x+2) \ge x!$$

This implies $x \le 5$ and thus $z \le 7$.

So now we finish: If $x,y \le 3$ then observe that $z$ satisfies $z \le 6$. So exhaustively check the triplets $(x,y,z); x, y, z \le 7$; $x=y$; $x,y,z$ positive integers.

***As pointed out by Silverfish, we do need to establish why we may assume that the inequality $y \le z$ holds. Assume otherwise, i.e., assume that the strict inequality $z<y$ holds. Then, as we may assume WLOG that the inequality $x \le y$ holds, so does
the string of inequalities $y! < x!+y!+z! = x!y! < 3y!$ holds, which would give $x!y!=2y!$ which gives $x=2$, and thus the equation $2y!=2+y!+z!$. This in turn implies the equation $z!=y!-2$. There is however no such integer $z$ satisfying this equation for any integer $y \ge 3$.

Comment: (+1) The equation is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ but not $z$. So "First, assume $x \le y$" can be done without loss of generality. But "First, assume $x \le y \le z$" isn't really valid unless at some stage you try the alternative assumptions with $z$ occupying the other possible positions in the inequality (and check they provide no solutions). I think the easiest thing to do is to just assume wlog that $x \le y$ and prove $y \le z$. [HvE's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123011/find-all-positive-integers-a-b-c-to-the-equation-ab-abc/4747025#comment4366215_2123011) is one way

Comment: Hi @Silverfish I edited my answer per your comment. Thanks for the good feedback!

Comment: Nicely done, actually that's different both to HvE's comment and [the method in my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4747025/72968), which required me to find some other bounds first! I think you can make it look a little neater: once you have $y! < x!y! < 3y!$ just divide by $y!$ to get $1<x!<3$ hence $x=2$. Saves the (slightly subtler) argument $x!y!=2y!$

Comment: In fact I think your method can even get you something better! Rather than just showing why you take $x \le y \le z$, you could even get $y < z$. Assume instead that $z \le y$ (you don't need this inequality to be strict). Then $y! < x! + y! + z! = x!y! \le 3y!$ and $1 < x! \le 3$. This still requires $x=2$ and no solutions.  Hence any solution has $y < z$.

Comment: Yes @Silverfish we do indeed get the *strict* inequality $y<z$ "at no extra charge". I am not sure how to apply to my answer above, maybe it applies to a different answer given here

Comment: I think in your approach knowing $y<z$ is mostly helpful in cutting down the triplets $(x,y,z)$ you need to check at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already proved that $a=b$, then

$a!b!=a!+b!+c!$

$(a!)^2=2.a!+c!$

$(a!)^2-2.a!-c!=0$

$(a!-1)^2-c!-1=0$

$c!=(a!-1)^2-1$

So, there is only value for $c$

Comment: Why doesn't this equation have solutions for $a$ arbitrarily large though?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Let $b \le a, 2 \le a$

$a! = \frac{a!}{b!} + 1 + \frac{c!}{b!}$

So, $a=b$ or $a=b+1$ or $c=b$ or $c = b+1$ (in another case left part is even, but right is odd)

Comment: Yeah well I have proven that a can only b, but why must c=b+1?

Comment: case if c = 2*k + 1 and a>b

Comment: Well, I think one can finish using this, but there is more work to be done. If $a=b$ and $c \ge b+4$ then $\frac{c!}{b!} \equiv_4 0$ which would imply $a! \equiv_4 2$ which would imply $a \le 3$. Then of course, $a$ and $b$ small implies $c$ must be small.

Comment: And so then if $a > 3$ then one can conclude $a! =2+ (a+1)(a+2)(a+3)$ which would imply $a$ small. BUT, the answer as given above is not what I would consider a good or complete answer as it doesn't illustrate the way through the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Without loss of generality, $b \ge a$.**

This follows since the equation $a!b! = a! + b! + c!$ is symmetric in $a$ and $b$. If $a > b$ we could just relabel the variables $a$ and $b$ and switch them around. Just remember, if asked to give *all* solutions, that if we find $(a,b,c)=(p,q,r)$ with $p < q$ then we will need to list the symmetric solution $(a,b,c)=(q,p,r)$ as well, even though our method might not find it explicitly as the alternative solution violates our assumption $b \ge a$ .

**There's a lower bound $b \ge a \ge 3$.**

By dispensing of small cases: if $a=1$ then $b! = 1 + b! + c!$ so $c! = -1$, which is impossible. If $a=2$ then $2a! = a! + c! + 2$ so $a! = c! + 2$, but no factorials differ by two: the smallest non-zero gap is $2!-1!=1$ and for $n \ge 3$ consecutive factorials differ by
$$n! - (n-1)! = n(n-1)! - (n-1)! = (n-1)(n-1)! \ge 2(2!) = 4$$

**This imposes a lower bound on $c$, with $c \ge b+1 > b \ge a \ge 3$.**

Since $b! \ge a! \ge 6$ we have $c! = a!b! - a! - b! \ge 6b! - b! - b! = 4b!$ so $c! > b!$ hence $c > b$.

(Adapted from Mike's answer, there's a different proof that $c \ge b+1$ that doesn't rely on establishing lower bounds for $a$ first. Suppose instead that $c \le b$ as well as $a \le b$. Then $b! < a!+b!+c! = a!b! \le 3(b!)$. Dividing by $b!$ gives $1<a!\le 3$ hence $a=2$, but this cannot give a solution for the reasons stated above. Therefore we must have $c > b$.)

**$c!$ must be a multiple of $b!$, and so is $a!$.**

From $c \ge b+1$ we know $c! = m(b!)$ where $m=c!/b!$ is the product of factors from $b+1$ to $c$. But $a! = a!b! - b! - c!$ so $a! = (a! - 1 - m)b!$.

**Hence $a=b$ and we must solve $b! - 2 = c!/b!$.**

From $b \ge a$ we already knew $a!$ divides $b!$. But we just showed $b!$ divides $a!$ also. Hence $a!=b!$ and (since $a\ge3$, so we don't need to worry about $0! = 1!$) we must have $a=b$. Our equation becomes $(b!)^2 = 2(b!) + c!$ so dividing by $b!$ gives $b! = 2 + c!/b!$.

**$c \not\ge b+3$ so either $b! - 2 = b+1$ or $b! - 2 = (b+1)(b+2)$.**

We know $b \ge 3$ so $b!$ is certainly divisible by $3$, and $b!-2 = c!/b!$ cannot be. If $c \ge b+3$ then $c!/b!$ would have three consecutive integer factors $(b+1)(b+2)(b+3)$ and so would be divisible by $3$, which is impossible. So we have bounded $c$ between $b+1 \le c \le b+2$ and $c!/b!$ is either $b+1$ or $(b+1)(b+2)$.

**There are many ways to finish off from here. One approach is to note factorials grow much faster than polynomials, so $b! = b+3$ (for the case $c=b+1$) and $b! = b^2 + 3b + 4$ (for the case $c=b+2$) only need to be checked for a few low $b$ values.**

We only need to check $b \ge 3$. In fact $b=3$ *is* a solution of $b! = b+3$, and for $b \ge 4$ we see $b! > b+3$. To prove this, note that for $b \ge 4$,

$$b! \ge b \times 3! > 2b = b + b > b + 3$$

Checking both $b=3$ and $b=4$ we find $b! < b^2 + 3b + 4$ but we see the inequality flips for $b \ge 5$. To prove this, note that for $b \ge 5$ we have $2b-2 > b+2$ so

$$b! \ge b(b-1) \times 3! > 4(b-1)^2  = (2b - 2)^2 > (b+2)^2 = b^2 + 4b + 4 > b^2 + 3b + 4 $$

Thus the only solution is $a=b=3$ with $c=b+1=4$, and we verify $3!3!=3!+3!+4!$ as required.

**Another approach is to note that $b!-2$ cannot be divided by any integer from $3$ to $b$, and use this divisibility fact to rule out $c=b+2$ and solve $b!-2=b+1$.**

If $c = b+2$ then $c!/b! = (b+1)(b+2)$ is the product of two consecutive integers, one of which is even. So either $(b+1)/2$ or $(b+2)/2$ is an integer factor of $c!/b!=b!-2$. Since $b\ge 3$ these potential factors are both at least $(3+1)/2=2$ but less than $(b+b)/2=b$. But every integer between $2$ and $b$ divides $b!$, so our factor $(b+i)/2$ (with $i\in\{1,2\}$) must divide both $b!$ and $b!-2$. Hence our factor must divide the difference, $b! - (b!-2) = 2$, and since our factor is at least $2$, it must *be* $2$. This can only happen when $b=3$, or else $(b+i)/2>2$ for $i=1,2$. Since $c=b+2$ we have $c!/b! = (b+1)(b+2) = 4 \times 5$ and $(b+1)/2=4/2=2$ is indeed a factor of $b!-2=3!-2=4$. But clearly $c!/b! \neq b!-2$ so this does not yield a solution.

Thus $c=b+1$ and we need to solve $b!-2=b+1$, or equivalently $b=b!-3$. So $b$ divides $b!-3$, but it also divides $b!$, hence it also divides the difference, $b! - (b!-3) = 3$. Since $b \ge 3$ and $b \mid 3$ we must have $b=3$, $a=b=3$, $c=b+1=4$ and we verify $3!3!=3!+3!+4!$ is a solution.

**A third approach is to consider the implications of $b+1$, and potentially $b+2$, dividing $b!-2$, to think what kind of prime factor decomposition they must have.**

Every positive integer $n$ is either one, prime, the square of a prime, or the product of two distinct nontrivial factors, $1 < f_1 < \sqrt{n} < f_2 < n$ with $n=f_1 f_2$.

We know $b!-2$ is either $b+1$ or $(b+1)(b+2)$ so $b+1$, and every factor dividing $b+1$ (as well as $b+2$ and every factor dividing $b+2$ if $c=b+2$), is also a factor of $b!-2$. We also know $b!-2$ is divisible by $2$ but not by any factor from $3$ to $b$.

Since $b \ge 3$, we can narrow those options for $b+1$ down to either being an odd prime, the square of a prime, or the product of two distinct nontrivial factors. If $b+1$ is an odd prime, we can't have $b!-2=b+1$ since the LHS is even. So we must have $c=b+2$ and $b!-2=(b+1)(b+2)$. Then $b+2$ is even, and so $b/2+1$ divides the RHS. But since $2 < b/2 + 1 < b$, it cannot divide the LHS. Hence $b+1$ is not an odd prime. But if $b+1$ is either the square of an odd prime, or the product of two distinct nontrivial factors, then $b+1$ must have a factor between $3$ and $b$, which is impossible for the same reason. The only possibility that remains is for $b+1$ to be the square of an even prime, i.e. $b=2^2-1=3$. Then $b!-2=3!-2=4$ equals $b+1=4$ but not $(b+1)(b+2)=4\times 5=20$. So our only solution has $c=b+1=4$, $a=b=3$, and $3!3!=3!+3!+4!$ as required.

This last approach is essentially [@kotomord's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2123081/72968) but adapted so it doesn't rely on knowledge of [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) to claim that $b+1$ divides $b!+1$ if $b+1$ is prime.