# Solve $~ x! + y! + z!= x!y! ~$ for integer set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I just got a little lost in the assumptions, I first assumed that $~y> x~$, but then I wasn't very successful.

Comment: Wolog you can assume $y\ge x$ becaus otherwise you can just relabel the variables.  But you shouldn't necessarily assume $y \ne x$.

Comment: Hope this is not an ongoing contest

Comment: @Peter The solution is already online at MSE, see the duplicate.

Comment: This question should be re-opened. Have you read the answers given via the link? They are no good.

Comment: That's why I asked, I didn't understand. but people here always warn to point out that it was duplicated, so I follow the rules

Comment: @Helen I answered your question on the other thread. I hope it helps!

Comment: To expand on @fleablood's point: this equation is symmetric in $x$ and $y$ but not $z$. You can either assume without loss of generality that $y \ge x$, or split it into two cases (you only need to deal with $y>x$ and $y=x$; the case $x>y$ is symmetric to the $y>x$ case). Just make sure if you find an answer with $y>x$ you also give the corresponding symmetric solution with $x>y$. (In fact in this case we can show $x=y$ e.g. [my answer on the other thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4747025/72968))